# UILabels or buttons will not show up in a table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I am very simply adding a TableView to a ViewController and add in a couple prototype cells. After dragging a UILabel to any one of the table cells, it does not work, regardless of whether or not constraints were added. When I do try to add constraints, I do that by adding missing constraints. I have not been using any code yet. This is all related to the storyboard. I can't seem to find the solution after extensive research on this.

Comment: @PhillipMills I'm not really sure what that means, but it's all just a TableView with a UILabel in one of the cells that does not show up.

Comment: I think you DO need to add code. Did you try to subclass UITableViewCell and then assign this new customed cell class to your prototype cells ? (In the "Custom Class" field in the identity inspector)